# java, implementing a method and running it. error?

Tags: java

Using eclipse I get the error .. Error: This method must return a result of type String

Isnt system.out.println a return type?..

stupid quesiton im sure..

```
 public class abc{  
     public static void main(String args[])
       {}

public static String getGrade(int score){

        if(score>= 0 && score<=10){
            System.out.println("Fail");

        }
        if(score>= 11 && score<=25){
            System.out.println("D");

        }
        if(score>= 26 && score<=40){
            System.out.println("C");


        }
        if(score>= 41 && score<=55){
            System.out.println("B");

        }
        if(score>= 56 && score<=100){
            System.out.println("A");

        }

    }

    getGrade(23);



}
```

Comment: You can't define a method inside of a method. You're trying to define `String static getGrade(int score)` inside of your `main` method

Comment: You should fix the errors one by one. So have a look at the first error, and if you can't fix it yourself post the error here.

Comment: Move `getGrade` outside of `main` but still inside of `abc`.

Comment: I see you've now edited the answer to implement people's suggestions, such that they don't make sense anymore. A second question would be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getGrade()  is not returning a string like expected hence u get that eroor

to solve that have a variable like String result =null at top;

instead of doing System.out.println("A") do result="A"
and similarly for other lines  i.e change System.out.println("B") to result="B" and so on...
and finnaly do
return result;

Comment: ohhhh, your answer makes so much sense, i feel so silly. Thanks Kaushik!

Answer (score 2):

You've implemented a method *within* a method.

```
     public static void main(String args[])
       {

public static String getGrade(int score){
```

which (unfortunately) Java won't let you do. Simply call `getGrade()` from within your `main()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You did

```
public class abc{  

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    //Method defined within a method???
    public static String getGrade(int score){
      ...
    }

    getGrade();
  }
}
```

Do this instead

```
public class abc{  

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    getGrade();
  }

  public static String getGrade(int score){
    ...
  }
}
```